# How do I add a property to my Xamarin page that I can use in a default style?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms, app.xaml

I have added a `BarTextColor` property to my custom Xamarin page, like so:

```
    public static readonly BindableProperty BarTextColorProperty = BindableProperty.Create("BarTextColor", typeof(Color), typeof(MyCustomPage), Color.Default);

    public Color BarTextColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(BarTextColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BarTextColorProperty, value); UpdateInnerViews(); }
    }
```

But when I try to set a global style in my App.xaml like so:

```
    <Style TargetType="myapp:MyCustomPage">
        <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="{StaticResource BarTextColor}"/>
    </Style>
```

I get this error:

> Property 'BarTextColor' must be a DependencyProperty to be set with a Setter

and this:

> The property "BarTextColor" is not a DependencyProperty. To be used in
>   markup, non-attached properties must be exposed on the target type
>   with an accessible instance property "BarTextColor". For attached
>   properties, the declaring type must provide static "GetBarTextColor" 
>   and "SetBarTextColor" methods.

What's going wrong?  The Xamarin source on github all uses `BindableProperty` not `DependencyProperty`, so why can't I?

(I'm using Visual Studio Community 2013 with Xamarin 2.3.1, in case it matters)

Answer (score 2):

I created `BasePage.cs`:

```
public class BasePage : ContentPage
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty BarTextColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create(nameof(BarTextColor),
                                typeof(Color),
                                typeof(BasePage),
                                Color.White,
                                propertyChanged: OnColorChanged);

    private static void OnColorChanged(BindableObject bindable, object oldValue, object newValue)
    {
    }

    public Color BarTextColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(BarTextColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(BarTextColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

Then created some `ContentPage`:

```
<local:BasePage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:SuperForms.Samples.CustomPropertySample;assembly=SuperForms.Samples"
                x:Class="SuperForms.Samples.CustomPropertySample.Page1"
                Style="{StaticResource BasePageStyle}">
    <Label Text="Alloha" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
</local:BasePage>

public partial class Page1 : BasePage
{
    public Page1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And declared `Style` in `App.xaml`:

```
<Application xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:customPropertySample="clr-namespace:SuperForms.Samples.CustomPropertySample;assembly=SuperForms.Samples"
         x:Class="SuperForms.Samples.App">
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="BasePageStyle" TargetType="customPropertySample:BasePage">
                <Setter Property="BarTextColor" Value="#ff0000"/>
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

But I used `Style` by `Key`, because it didn't work w/o `Key`.
And on `OnColorChanged` I've got red color from `Style`.

**Edited**

Or you could create base page for navigation:

```
public class BaseNavigationPage : NavigationPage
{
    public BaseNavigationPage(ContentPage root) 
        : base(root)
    {

    }

    public BaseNavigationPage()
    {
        BarBackgroundColor = Color.Red;
    }
}
```

And use it for Navigation:

```
    public App()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        MainPage = new CustomPropertySample.BaseNavigationPage(new CustomPropertySample.Page1());
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to globally style my pages.  I can't just set an explicit style on every page.  So I need the version without the Key.

Comment: @Simon Added one more suggestion.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm doing at the moment, but it's not sustainable as the number of pages I have increases.  I really need to set global styles.

Comment: Seems, that it's known bug. But in the [topic](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/34798/how-to-add-global-background-color-style) presented some workaround.